# how to toggle everything between a clicked class and the next same class?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='folder lev1'>323</div>
<div class='folder lev2'>525</div>
<div class='file lev3'>727</div>
<div class='file lev4'>1625</div>
<div class='folder lev1'>new</div>
```

js

I need to toggle everything between clicked `lev1` and the next `lev1` element.

I tried:

```
$(".lev1").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".lev2").toggle();
    $(this).next(".lev2").next(".lev3").next(".lev4").toggle();
});
```

Doesn't work. Only `.lev2` is toggled.

Comment: If you added a `.` to lev3, then the second should also toggle lev4 (but only lev4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$(".lev1").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".lev1").toggle();
});
```

```js
$(".lev1").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".lev1").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='folder lev1'>323</div>
<div class='folder lev2'>525</div>
<div class='file lev3'>727</div>
<div class='file lev4'>1625</div>
<div class='folder lev1'>new</div>
```